# Does anybody know the list of Pentaho Data Integration (Kettle) connectors list?

Tags: etl, pentaho, kettle

I am doing comparison between three open source ETL tools Talend, Kettle and CloverETL.

I could find with no problem Talend and CloverETL's connector list.
But, I cannot find the one for Kettle.

Does someone knows them or where can I find them ?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Check this out: https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/9.0/Setup/Components_Reference#Java_virtual_machine (as of Jan 2021)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume by "connector" you mean input/output nodes and not intermediate transformations. Just looking through the Kettle GUI, I see:

**Inputs**

- Access
- CSV
- De-serialize from file [GH: not sure what kind of file/serialization this means]
- ESRI Shapefiles
- Excel
- Fixed File
- Generate Random
- File system functions (file name, row count, etc)
- XML
- LDAP
- LDIF
- Mondrian
- Property [GH: a Java-style .properties file perhaps?]
- RSS
- S3 CSV
- Salesforce
- [Database] Table
- Text File
- XBase

**Outputs**

- Access
- Excel
- DB Table
- Properties [GH: again, I'm guessing a Java-style .properties file]
- RSS
- SQL File
- Serialize to File
- Text File
- XML

Comment: By any chance would you know what type of database we are talking about ? Al the one available in the marker ?

Comment: Any database that has a JDBC driver. i.e. most of them!

Answer (score 3):

This is the updated list for Pentaho Input/Output connectors as at 25-Nov-2011 summarised from [Pentaho Data Integration Steps](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Pentaho+Data+Integration+Steps).

### Input and Output

- Amazon S3
- Cassandra
- HBase
- Java Property
- JDBC databases
- Json
- LDAP
- Microsoft Access
- Microsoft Excel
- OpenERP
- Palo Cell
- Palo Dimension
- RSS
- Salesforce
- Text file
- XML

### Input Only

- CSV Text file
- email
- Zip file (GZIP)
- LDIF
- Mondian
- MongoDB
- OLAP
- SAP
- SAS
- XBase (DBF)
- Yaml

### Bulk Load (input)

- ElasticSearch
- Greenplum
- Infobright
- Ingres VectorWise
- LucidDB
- MonetDB
- MySQL
- Oracle
- PostgreSQL
- Teradata